# Weird Missing Partial error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

Hello I am having a weird error in my rails app.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing partial foo/bar, application/bar with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: blah blah
):
  app/controllers/foo_controller.rb:9:in `doSomething'
```

Now I am pretty darn sure in app/views/foo has bar.html.erb file. Any ideas? I heard this can sometimes happen when there may be a space in the file name but this isn't it. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add the code that raises the error so we don't have to guess into the blue? ;)

Comment: when you calling partial using render "bar", inside foo directory there must be _bar.html.erb, would you show me the code of foo_controller

Answer (score 2):

in `app/views/foo bar.html.erb` should be `_bar.html.erb`, as all partial names should start with `"_"`

Answer (score 1):

Partial name start with "_" underscore. Looks like you have missed underscore in in prefix bar.html.erb

Comment: You're a savior. I thought the underscore was only prefixed when a name wasn't specially given as an argument to render. Thanks a million